# PUN2 | The process is called twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently using PUN2 to create a multiplayer shooting game.
Participation in a room and synchronization of movement and bullets have been implemented.

However, the processing when hit is performed twice.
Perhaps this is because the exact same object that exists on the two devices is processing each shot. (maybe)

How do I avoid duplicate hit handling?

#### Code:

*flow : The shooter assigns its own identification number to the shell and fires it → Anyone who hits the shell will take damage.*

**Player.cs**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collider)
{
        BulletController bulletController = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletController>();

        if (photonView.Owner.ActorNumber != bulletController.shooterUserId)
        {
            photonView.RPC(nameof(Damaged), RpcTarget.All, bulletController.Damage, bulletController.shooterUserId);
            bulletController.Remove();
        }
}

[PunRPC]
void Damaged(int damage, int userId)
{
    var hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable["HP"] = HP;
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(hashtable);

    if (photonView.IsMine)
    {
        HP -= damage;
        if (HP <= 0)
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            HP = 0;

            if (userId != photonView.OwnerActorNr)
                photonView.RPC("KilledPlayer", RpcTarget.Others);

        }
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void KilledPlayer()
{
    GameSparksLeaderboard.SaveXP(100);
}
```

Comment: You need to decide how to manage logic: usually it's either *authoritative server* (meaning the server is the only one to calculate important stuff like bullets hitting, and sends the result to all the "dumb" clients) or *peer to peer* where each peer has control on his objects, meaning if player A fires, he calculates if he hit anyone and the result, and if B fires, he has the control to do it. So it seems to me you need to decide on your approach and stick with it

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) 
Does that mean "the player who shoots calculates" or "the player who is hit calculates"? Then I want to do the latter.
The hit player performs **Damaged (int damage, int userId)** and does not want to be executed by other devices.

Comment: That is also an option, but probably the worst one IMHO. I've developed several fast paced real time multiplayer games, and found that P2P with each client saying "I hit X" gives the overall best experience for the least amount of effort/expenses in most cases. If you will calculate hits by the hit player, I am pretty sure the experience will not be a good one for the people shooting. If you have a first person game with hitscan weapons, usually going for the first approach is the most cost effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to attach `photonView.IsMine`.
It's important, but it's easy to forget ...